# PHP: How to create a good foreach shorthand?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a simple object (*or array*) like this...

```
stdClass Object (
[people] => Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [name] => 'John',
        [age] => 50,
    )

    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [name] => 'Martin',
        [age] => 47,
    )
)
```

And I can easily loop through it using foreach like this

```
foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo $person->name . '<br>';
}
```

But I would somehow like to have a **shorter way** to echo all names with something like this...

```
print_each($people->name)
```

And it would do exactly the same thing **with only 1 short line of code** as my 3 lines of foreach code did.

Is there a function like this or how would we go about creating a function like that?

Comment: why? readability should never be underestimated.  if you must, write a function/method.

Comment: For testing/debugging purpuses. How to write a function like that?

Comment: put the foreach in a function?

Answer (score 6):

You can use array_column and implode.

```
echo implode("<br>\n", array_column($arr, "name"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably `array_map` is the closest to what you want.

```
array_map(function($person) { echo $person->name; }, $people);
```

Comment: stil too long, can we write a shorter function?

Comment: Sure! How about `array_map(function($p) { echo $p->name; }, $people);` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Shortest way and not that ugly would be to add a 
***__toString*** 
Method to the Person Object like this:

```
class Person {
    public $name;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->name;
    }
}
```

This then enables you to use the very super short:

```
array_walk($people, 'printf');
```

Syntax.

Comment: Looks like they're just StdClass objects in this case, but in general I think it's a good idea!

Answer (score 2):

If you have array, you can use `array_column` for that:

```
$people = [
    ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 3],
    ['name' => 'Carl', 'age' => 43]
];

var_dump(
    array_column($people, 'name') 
);

 /*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "John"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Carl"
}
```

Comment: That's nice but only for arrays not objects

Comment: @MartinZeltin array_column works on arrays of objects, unless you're still using PHP 5.

Comment: this is exactly what i need

Answer (score 2):

Since **PHP 7.4** you can do:

```php
echo implode('', array_map(fn($person) => $person->name . '<br>', $people));
```

1. The inner `array_map()` function takes as **second parameter** your initial array **$people**.
2. The inner `array_map()` function takes as **first parameter** an arrow function `fn() =>` that gets the single items **$person** out of your initial array **$people**
3. inside the arrow function each **$person->name** gets concated with `'<br>'` and written as value in a new array.
4. this new array will be returned by the `array_map()` function
5. The items of this array will be passed as **second parameter** to the `implode()` function and glued together with the empty string `''`.
6. the entire string that `implode()` returns gets `echo`ed out

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get "smart" about it you can write something like this:

```
 array_walk_recursive($a, function($v, $k) {echo $k === 'name' ? $v : '';});
```

But being smart over readability is a bad idea, always.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to write a function to do that, it would be something along these lines:

```
function print_each($collection, $property) {
  foreach ($collection as $item) {
    echo $item->$property . "<br />";
  }
}
```

Which could be used like so:

```
$people = [
  (object)[
    "name" => "Bob",
    "age" => 25
  ],
  (object)[
    "name" => "Dan",
    "age" => 31
  ],
  (object)[
    "name" => "Sally",
    "age" => 45
  ]
];

print_each($people, "name"); // prints "Bob<br />Dan<br />Sally<br />"
```